# How to make a UITextView fill up the remaining space

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIButton` and `UITextField` side by side as follows.

[image]

I want the Add button to only have a width based on the content. And the text view shall take up the rest of the space. I have the following auto layout constraints.

```
private func setupLayout() {
    newDeviceIdTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: deviceIdLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    newDeviceIdTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true

    newDeviceIdButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: deviceIdLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    newDeviceIdButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    newDeviceIdButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newDeviceIdTextField.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

In [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html) article there is a section which I believe exactly solves my problem. But I just don't understand how.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks more like a UITextField. Is it? Makes a big difference... Also _where_ do you want the right side of the button?

Comment: Good point. Right. I didn't update the variable names. Shame on me. I updated the post.

Comment: @matt The right side of the button shall be at the right side of the parent view. So basically, the button is on the right and has a width based on the title. The textfield shall take up the rest of the horizontal space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button automatically sizes its width to fit its content, and both a text field and a button have an automatic height. So what you want to do is trivial:

Pin the left of the text field where you want it.

Pin the right of the button where you want it.

Pin the tops of both where you want them.

Pin the right of the text field to the left of the button and set that constant to a small number such as 8.

Comment: OK. It works now. The only thing that changed is that I removed the last line and basically turned it around as you said. But I don't understand what's different now. One time I say the leading anchor of the button is the trailing anchor of the text field (doesn't work). The other time I say that the trailing anchor of the text field is the leading anchor of the button (works). Isn't this the same?

Comment: No, it's not. Now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: No they are reverse of one another. For the one that doesn’t work I think it would work if you supplied a negative constant, but I’m not sitting at a computer so I can’t test. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without writing code, from storyboard. What i do for this kind of UI is,

1. Pin the left of the text field where you want it.
2. Pin the right of the button where you want it.
3. Pin the tops of both where you want them.
4. Pin the right of the text field to the left of the button

It's look like in image below

[image]

Now Select button > Size Inspector > In Content hugging Priority

Change Horizontal to 750(high) and you done :)

[image]

Result look like in image below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd rather go with code because storyboard/xib are (more or less) human-**un**readable. Also, I don't like the idea of changing the content hugging priority because I don't understand yet what the impact is on the rest of the screen. Still learning :)